# Stringify object for qs parser

Tags: mongodb, parsing, express, query-string, stringify

Express js uses [qs parser](https://github.com/hapijs/qs) to parse query strings into objects. Is there a lib out there for use on front-end applications that does the reverse? I would love to be able to write a mongo db query on the front end in object form and have it parsed automatically into the format qs parser is expecting right before the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

> I would love to be able to write a mongo db query on the front end in object form

You should absolutely **not do this** unless you're OK with essentially giving any user of your web app an open shell to do whatever they want to your database.

But with that said, I found this in bower.io:

https://github.com/fernandofleury/query-object

More here:

http://bower.io/search/?q=qs

Comment: Wouldn't an attacker already have exactly the same capability by sending queries in string form? All of our querys hit GET routes only, could someone even do any damage that way?

Comment: right so this should be no different to whats already in place. using express, an equivalent query to yours is `GET /users?q[drop]=students`. it ought to be exactly as safe to write objects and parse them as to write the equivalent query out in string form

Comment: express doesn't automatically convert something like `?q[drop]=students` into a mongo query that blindly gets executed, you have to implement that yourself, and it's equally bad idea. You should design your `GET /users` API in such a way that the only thing it can possibly do is fetch users.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question, I suppose you don't need it anymore, but I hope this helps other users who end up here:

Meet [graphQL](https://graphql.org/). It's an open standard, which lets you query backend api's in a flexible manner.

Mongodb even supports it out of the box and it is permission based, so no worries about frontend users hacking into your database (you should of course properly configure those permissions to limit access to specific resources).

Read more on https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql